How to Trigger Email Verification Link in Clerk Backend After Creating a User Programmatically?
I'm working on a custom authentication flow using Clerk in my Next.js app. Instead of using the <SignUp/> component provided by Clerk, I'm creating users programmatically in the backend with the following code:
const clerkUser = await clerkClient.users.createUser({
  emailAddress: [data.email],
  firstName: data.firstName,
  lastName: data.lastName,
  password: data.password,
});

This works fine, and the user is created. However, I've noticed that the email address is automatically marked as "verified."
What I want to achieve is to send an email verification link to the user after sign-up, so they can verify their email address.
How can I trigger the email verification process manually after creating a user in the backend using Clerk?
Is there a way to prevent the email from being marked as verified by default, or an API call to send the verification link post-creation?

Did you solve it?

I've reached out to the support and they said its not possible, currently.

Yep, same here. They said to me to open a ticket here: feedback.clerk.com/roadmap can you do the same?
